# Java GUI: Can the JLabel hold an object/class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, chess

I'm in the middle of a java chess game build and am attempting to build the GUI portion of it. The GUI Board is complete, and I am able to set pieces on the board. Instead of simply setting an image as the piece, I want to be able to set a new instantiation of a Rook class which takes in the color and image.I need the JLabel piece to do this so later on in the code, I can add methods that make the rook abide by turn-taking and the move rules.

From what I know, JLabel only can hold an image or text, so I'm left believing that this might be impossible. Any help would be appreciated. My specific questions would be:

- **Is it possible to have the JLabel be an Rook Object that carries a color and image? If so, how?**
- **If its not possible, what are some alternatives to setting a piece on the board that instatiates the piece clearly (as a rook, pawn, ...) and sets its image and color?**

  Any help would be greately appreciated.

code:

```
    // Sets a piece on the board    
    JLabel piece = new JLabel("whiteRook.png"); //want this to be a new instantiation of a Rook
    JPanel panel = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
    panel.add(piece);
    
    //  Failed Attempt ---------------------------------------------------//
    
    //      String color = "white";
    //      ImageIcon WhiteRook = new ImageIcon("whiteRook.png");
    //      Rook firstRook = new Rook(color, WhiteRook);
    //      
    //      piece = new JLabel(firstRook);
    //      panel = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
    //      panel.add(piece);
```

Comment: Do you have different images for the black and white pieces? I guess I'm wondering what the `Color` is for

Comment: I would use `JPanel` per square. There is no performance problem since you use fixed square count and its easy to handle styles, BG, images ....

Comment: can you giv  the code of the rook class

Comment: If i got it correctly it should be simple to extend JLabel creating your own JLabel with extra attributes. Your class will behave like a JLabel when u need it, and will hold all the rest as well.

Comment: ^------ Exactly. Make your own subclass of JLabel and then you can have that object hold any data you want.

Comment: 1. please whats JPanel panel = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);, where do you go 2. you have to change setOpaque, 3. JLabes laid in JPanel haven't something with chesses figurines, 4. you can to start with Unicode Glyps, there are all figurines, change only Font Size is required

Comment: To answer: PeeSkillet, I do have different images for the black and white pieces. In the game, pieces routinely have to check if another piece is black or white, so i'd rather not parse their image names. Maxim, I do use JPanel per square.

Answer (score 2):

I was developing a chess application recently. What I employed was subclassed `JLabel` for each of the 64 squares.

Here is the relevant code and a sample screenshot

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;

public class Cell extends JLabel
{
    Color backgroundColor;
    boolean highlight=false;
    Color highlightColor=new Color(132, 146, 255);

    Border blackBorder=BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);

    public void setBackgroundImage(ImageIcon backgroundImage)
    {
        setIcon(backgroundImage);
    }

    public Cell(Color backGroundColor, ImageIcon backgroundImage)
    {
        super(backgroundImage);
        this.backgroundColor=backGroundColor;
        setBorder(blackBorder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if(!highlight) g.setColor(backgroundColor);
        else g.setColor(highlightColor);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public void setHighlightMode(boolean status)
    {
        if(status==highlight) return;
        highlight=status;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Have a custom `JPanel` for each piece. Have the cunstructor take in a `ChessPiece` object. Draw the image and do something with the color

```
public class PiecePanel extends JPanel{
     private static final D_W = 50;
     private static final D_H = 50;
     BufferedImage img;
     Color color;

     public PiecePanel(ChessPiece piece) {
         color = piece.getColor();
         try {
             img = ImageIO.read(piece.getImagePath());
         } catch (IOException ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.setColor(color);
         // do something with color
         g.drawImage(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
     }

     public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
         return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
     }
}
```

Then you can instantiate each `ChessPiece` panel like this

```
ChessPiece bRook1 = new Rook(path, color);
JPanel blackRook1 = new PiecePanel(bRook1);
```

You could do the same subclassing JLabel. But it's new preffered to paint on JLabel. If you don't want to do any extra painting, just Sublclass JLabel.

Comment: I'll try this. I'll upvote/mark as an answer if i can get it to work :)